# merge three odoo (postgreSQL) databases in one database

Tags: sql, postgresql, etl, odoo

I have 3 databases with:

- same tables
- same schema
- different data

I want to merge all the 3 databases into one database and I want the result database to be recognized by odoo.

I think that to do that I have to copy data of each table from each databases into the target, but as you know odoo when store data,it use an autoincrement primary key for all the tables and, when I copy those tables I have to synchronize the ids of the foreign keys related to those tables, as I see this maybe the only problem I will face.

So my request is: I need a tool to synchronize the foreign keys automatically after the data has been moved to the target database.

(brief : suggest to me the shortest path to do the work).

Comment: Use some ETL library/software. This question is very broad. Voting to close.

Comment: @TheImpaler why ETL ? i have 3 databases with exactly the same properties i want a heavy solution, just little sql Query or a postgreSQL extension or an odoo module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you familiar with Odoo's external ids (also referred as `xmlids`)? They are kind of pointers that are stored in a table named `ir_model_data`. The `xmlid` is the result of concatenating the `module` and `name` fields using a dot as a separator and it points to a record on the table corresponding to the `model` field which also has an `id` equal to the value of the `res_id` field.

So, write a script that connects to the 3 databases and, one table at the time, takes a record, see if it exists on the other two databases, assigns an external id in a clever way and propagates it to the other databases which have the same record.

Then export your tables using Odoo's export function from two databases and load them in the third one.

Be sure to backup your databases first and never work on the original databases but on copies.

Disclaimer: This approach may or may not work depending on the complexity of your database, the data contained therein and your algorithms to identify whether a record exists or not in the other databases.